# Dynamically change entry and rangeslider values in custom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, rangeslider, customtkinter

I have a rangeslider with 2 sliding values (lower and higher) and 2 entry boxes.

I would like to bind these entry boxes with the slider values of the rangeslider. That is, if i input some value in the entry box, the current value of slider changes automatically. Similarly, if I change the value of slider, the value in the entry box changes automatically.

I was trying to approach this by using the variables in CTKEntry and CTKRangeSlider but it is not working. Here is my approach:

```
hVar1 = tk.DoubleVar()  #left handle variable
hVar2 = tk.DoubleVar()  #right handle variable
            
range_slider = CTkRangeSlider(self.tabview.tab("Halos"), variables=[hVar1,hVar2], width = 400, from_=0, to=100) 
range_slider.place(x=400, y=20)
       
        
self.entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Halos"), placeholder_text=hVar1.get(), textvariable=hVar1, width=50)
self.entry1.place(x=200, y=20)

self.entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Halos"), placeholder_text=hVar2.get(), textvariable=hVar2, width=50)
self.entry2.place(x=300, y=20)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the two `DoubleVar` to different initial values, for example, 0 and 100?

Comment: Yes! I used value=0 and value=100 as the initial values for the `DoubleVar`.
Still does not help

Comment: It works for me if setting different initial values.  It is better to post a [mre].

Comment: Wow! I tried it in terminal and it worked but it does not work in jupyter notebook. That is weird!! Thanks a lot though